# JS: Remove object from nested array and return parent array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

How do I remove the object in my array subBrands that is nested inside another array where the id property of an object is = to 31. I'm trying to get the whole parent array back without that subBrand removed.

Array is:

```
[
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Parent Brand 1",
    "parent": null,
    "author": 1,
    "deleted_at": null,
    "created_at": "2017-02-02 09:55:51",
    "updated_at": "2017-02-02 09:55:51",
    "subBrands": [
      {
        "id": 31,
        "name": "Sub Brand 6",
        "parent": 10,
        "author": 1,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "created_at": "2017-02-02 11:24:49",
        "updated_at": "2017-02-02 11:42:02"
      },
      {
        "id": 32,
        "name": "Sub Brand 7",
        "parent": 10,
        "author": 1,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "created_at": "2017-02-02 11:24:57",
        "updated_at": "2017-02-02 11:42:18"
      },
      {
        "id": 33,
        "name": "Sub Brand 8",
        "parent": 10,
        "author": 1,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "created_at": "2017-02-02 11:25:04",
        "updated_at": "2017-02-02 11:42:34"
      },
      {
        "id": 34,
        "name": "Sub Brand 9",
        "parent": 10,
        "author": 1,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "created_at": "2017-02-02 11:25:39",
        "updated_at": "2017-02-02 11:42:43"
      },
      {
        "id": 35,
        "name": "Sub Brand 10",
        "parent": 10,
        "author": 1,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "created_at": "2017-02-02 11:25:46",
        "updated_at": "2017-02-02 11:42:52"
      },
      {
        "id": 36,
        "name": "Sub Brand 4",
        "parent": 10,
        "author": 1,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "created_at": "2017-02-02 11:43:53",
        "updated_at": "2017-02-02 11:43:53"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "name": "Parent Brand 2",
    "parent": null,
    "author": 1,
    "deleted_at": null,
    "created_at": "2017-02-02 09:56:16",
    "updated_at": "2017-02-02 09:56:16",
    "subBrands": []
  },
  {
    "id": 16,
    "name": "Brand no children",
    "parent": null,
    "author": 1,
    "deleted_at": null,
    "created_at": "2017-02-02 10:37:40",
    "updated_at": "2017-02-02 10:37:40",
    "subBrands": []
  },
  {
    "id": 37,
    "name": "Whoops brand",
    "parent": null,
    "author": 1,
    "deleted_at": null,
    "created_at": "2017-02-02 11:44:10",
    "updated_at": "2017-02-02 11:44:10",
    "subBrands": []
  }
]
```

What I'm trying to get is:

```
[
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Parent Brand 1",
    "parent": null,
    "author": 1,
    "deleted_at": null,
    "created_at": "2017-02-02 09:55:51",
    "updated_at": "2017-02-02 09:55:51",
    "subBrands": [
      {
        "id": 32,
        "name": "Sub Brand 7",
        "parent": 10,
        "author": 1,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "created_at": "2017-02-02 11:24:57",
        "updated_at": "2017-02-02 11:42:18"
      },
      {
        "id": 33,
        "name": "Sub Brand 8",
        "parent": 10,
        "author": 1,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "created_at": "2017-02-02 11:25:04",
        "updated_at": "2017-02-02 11:42:34"
      },
      {
        "id": 34,
        "name": "Sub Brand 9",
        "parent": 10,
        "author": 1,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "created_at": "2017-02-02 11:25:39",
        "updated_at": "2017-02-02 11:42:43"
      },
      {
        "id": 35,
        "name": "Sub Brand 10",
        "parent": 10,
        "author": 1,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "created_at": "2017-02-02 11:25:46",
        "updated_at": "2017-02-02 11:42:52"
      },
      {
        "id": 36,
        "name": "Sub Brand 4",
        "parent": 10,
        "author": 1,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "created_at": "2017-02-02 11:43:53",
        "updated_at": "2017-02-02 11:43:53"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "name": "Parent Brand 2",
    "parent": null,
    "author": 1,
    "deleted_at": null,
    "created_at": "2017-02-02 09:56:16",
    "updated_at": "2017-02-02 09:56:16",
    "subBrands": []
  },
  {
    "id": 16,
    "name": "Brand no children",
    "parent": null,
    "author": 1,
    "deleted_at": null,
    "created_at": "2017-02-02 10:37:40",
    "updated_at": "2017-02-02 10:37:40",
    "subBrands": []
  },
  {
    "id": 37,
    "name": "Whoops brand",
    "parent": null,
    "author": 1,
    "deleted_at": null,
    "created_at": "2017-02-02 11:44:10",
    "updated_at": "2017-02-02 11:44:10",
    "subBrands": []
  }
]
```

I'm open to using underscores. The closest I'm come is:

```
    var brands = _.filter(brands, function(n) { 
        return _.some(n.subBrands, function(subBrand){ 
            return subBrand.id != brand.id;
        });
    });
```

But that removes the arrays that don't contain a subBrand with an id of 31. So it's not very close to what I need.

Cheers!

Comment: should it work for any depth? or just for the second level?

Comment: @NinaScholz For the moment I just need it for a second level. Hopefully won't need it for any more.

Comment: _"I'm trying to get the whole parent array back without that subBrand removed."_ Do you mean with the object removed?

Comment: @guest271314 Nope the whole thing back without the subbrand with an ID of 31. The second array is an example of what I'm trying to get back.

Comment: @BarryWalsh Yes, are you trying to remove object with `id` `31` from `subBrands` array?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```js
var arr = [{"id":10,"name":"Parent Brand 1","parent":null,"author":1,"deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2017-02-02 09:55:51","updated_at":"2017-02-02 09:55:51","subBrands":[{"id":31,"name":"Sub Brand 6","parent":10,"author":1,"deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2017-02-02 11:24:49","updated_at":"2017-02-02 11:42:02"},{"id":32,"name":"Sub Brand 7","parent":10,"author":1,"deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2017-02-02 11:24:57","updated_at":"2017-02-02 11:42:18"},{"id":33,"name":"Sub Brand 8","parent":10,"author":1,"deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2017-02-02 11:25:04","updated_at":"2017-02-02 11:42:34"},{"id":34,"name":"Sub Brand 9","parent":10,"author":1,"deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2017-02-02 11:25:39","updated_at":"2017-02-02 11:42:43"},{"id":35,"name":"Sub Brand 10","parent":10,"author":1,"deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2017-02-02 11:25:46","updated_at":"2017-02-02 11:42:52"},{"id":36,"name":"Sub Brand 4","parent":10,"author":1,"deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2017-02-02 11:43:53","updated_at":"2017-02-02 11:43:53"}]},{"id":12,"name":"Parent Brand 2","parent":null,"author":1,"deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2017-02-02 09:56:16","updated_at":"2017-02-02 09:56:16","subBrands":[]},{"id":16,"name":"Brand no children","parent":null,"author":1,"deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2017-02-02 10:37:40","updated_at":"2017-02-02 10:37:40","subBrands":[]},{"id":37,"name":"Whoops brand","parent":null,"author":1,"deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2017-02-02 11:44:10","updated_at":"2017-02-02 11:44:10","subBrands":[]}];


var id = prompt("Id of subbrands to remove: ");

arr.forEach(function(o) {
  o.subBrands = o.subBrands.filter(s => s.id != id);
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: you create all new reference by filtering an array. this looks a bit over the top for this purpose, even if there is not an object with the wanted id, you yield a new array.

Comment: Why should a new array be created at each iteration at `.forEach()`, where requirement is to remove an object from existing array?

Comment: @NinaScholz @guest271314 If you consider that the only other approach is to call `forEach` and `splice` on each found element, this will be the best.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir _"If you consider that the only other approach is to call `forEach` and `splice` on each found element, this will be the best."_ That is not the only other possible approach. That is the pattern that you have selected to use. What do you mean by "best"? Creating a new array is not necessary to achieve expected result of removing an object from an existing array.

Comment: @BarryWalsh, i don't know, if i am the right person, my proposal is below, but anyway do you need one original array and another without the specific id? or just one?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I'm seeing something a bit odd so just want to make sure it isn't coming from something in your answer. For some reason when I run that it overwrites the value of two different arrays with the same value. So I have two variables with the same value initially, one will store the filtered version. But when I run that function without referencing the other variable both are updated. It's really weird – BarryWalsh 9 mins ago

Comment: @NinaScholz whoops, sorry about that. I'll try that now cheers!

Comment: @BarryWalsh you want the result to be stored in a new array and not overriding the original?

Answer (score 4):

You could iterate the parent part, and the children and if found splice the object.

```js
var data = [{ id: 10, name: "Parent Brand 1", parent: null, author: 1, deleted_at: null, created_at: "2017-02-02 09:55:51", updated_at: "2017-02-02 09:55:51", subBrands: [{ id: 31, name: "Sub Brand 6", parent: 10, author: 1, deleted_at: null, created_at: "2017-02-02 11:24:49", updated_at: "2017-02-02 11:42:02" }, { id: 32, name: "Sub Brand 7", parent: 10, author: 1, deleted_at: null, created_at: "2017-02-02 11:24:57", updated_at: "2017-02-02 11:42:18" }, { id: 33, name: "Sub Brand 8", parent: 10, author: 1, deleted_at: null, created_at: "2017-02-02 11:25:04", updated_at: "2017-02-02 11:42:34" }, { id: 34, name: "Sub Brand 9", parent: 10, author: 1, deleted_at: null, created_at: "2017-02-02 11:25:39", updated_at: "2017-02-02 11:42:43" }, { id: 35, name: "Sub Brand 10", parent: 10, author: 1, deleted_at: null, created_at: "2017-02-02 11:25:46", updated_at: "2017-02-02 11:42:52" }, { id: 36, name: "Sub Brand 4", parent: 10, author: 1, deleted_at: null, created_at: "2017-02-02 11:43:53", updated_at: "2017-02-02 11:43:53" }] }, { id: 12, name: "Parent Brand 2", parent: null, author: 1, deleted_at: null, created_at: "2017-02-02 09:56:16", updated_at: "2017-02-02 09:56:16", subBrands: [] }, { id: 16, name: "Brand no children", parent: null, author: 1, deleted_at: null, created_at: "2017-02-02 10:37:40", updated_at: "2017-02-02 10:37:40", subBrands: [] }, { id: 37, name: "Whoops brand", parent: null, author: 1, deleted_at: null, created_at: "2017-02-02 11:44:10", updated_at: "2017-02-02 11:44:10", subBrands: [] }];

data.some(function (a) {
    return a.subBrands.some(function (b, i, bb) {
        if (b.id === 31) {
            bb.splice(i, 1);
            return true;
        }
    });
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This will remove the match subBrands of only the first found object that contained them. Consider `arr = [{sb: [id:31]}, {sb: [id:31]}, {sb: [id:31]}]` will remove only the first object found by `some`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir, i am assuming all `id` are unique. no need to filter all sub array. this generates new references, which are not necessary. save the environment.

Comment: I'm not talking about the subBrands array itself (those ID should be unique). I'm talking about different objects that contain a subBrand array.

Comment: Plus this is not a typlical use of `some`. It should be used just to check if an item match some criteria or not (as lookahead for other stuff).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir _"Plus this is not a typlical use of some. It should be used just to check if an item match some criteria or not (as lookahead for other stuff)."_ ? What do you mean by "should be used"? There are no restrictions on use of `Array.prototype` methods for different tasks.

Answer (score 4):

I nest two `forEach` loops and return when the item has been found and removed:

```js
let items = [{id: 1, subItems: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]}];

const subItemToBeRemovedId = 1;

items.forEach((item) => item.subItems.forEach((subItem, index) => {
    if (subItem.id === subItemToBeRemovedId) {
        return item.subItems.splice(index, 1);
    }
}));

console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 1):

foreach seems to work:

```js
var brands=[{id:10,name:"Parent Brand 1",parent:null,author:1,deleted_at:null,created_at:"2017-02-02 09:55:51",updated_at:"2017-02-02 09:55:51",subBrands:[{id:31,name:"Sub Brand 6",parent:10,author:1,deleted_at:null,created_at:"2017-02-02 11:24:49",updated_at:"2017-02-02 11:42:02"},{id:32,name:"Sub Brand 7",parent:10,author:1,deleted_at:null,created_at:"2017-02-02 11:24:57",updated_at:"2017-02-02 11:42:18"},{id:33,name:"Sub Brand 8",parent:10,author:1,deleted_at:null,created_at:"2017-02-02 11:25:04",updated_at:"2017-02-02 11:42:34"},{id:34,name:"Sub Brand 9",parent:10,author:1,deleted_at:null,created_at:"2017-02-02 11:25:39",updated_at:"2017-02-02 11:42:43"},{id:35,name:"Sub Brand 10",parent:10,author:1,deleted_at:null,created_at:"2017-02-02 11:25:46",updated_at:"2017-02-02 11:42:52"},{id:36,name:"Sub Brand 4",parent:10,author:1,deleted_at:null,created_at:"2017-02-02 11:43:53",updated_at:"2017-02-02 11:43:53"}]},{id:12,name:"Parent Brand 2",parent:null,author:1,deleted_at:null,created_at:"2017-02-02 09:56:16",updated_at:"2017-02-02 09:56:16",subBrands:[]},{id:16,name:"Brand no children",parent:null,author:1,deleted_at:null,created_at:"2017-02-02 10:37:40",updated_at:"2017-02-02 10:37:40",subBrands:[]},{id:37,name:"Whoops brand",parent:null,author:1,deleted_at:null,created_at:"2017-02-02 11:44:10",updated_at:"2017-02-02 11:44:10",subBrands:[]}];

brands.forEach(function(brand) {
    brand.subBrands = brand.subBrands.filter(function(subBrand){
      return subBrand.id != 31;
  })  
});

console.log(brands);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to look into the "subBrands" property of each item of your array, and you are using underscore, this works:

```
var myBrand = _.each(brands, function(brand) {
  brand.subBrands = _.filter(brand.subBrands, function(subBrand) {
    return subBrand.id != 31;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery way

```
function removeById(data, id){

   $(data).each(function(i, e){

      if(e.subBrands.length > 0){

         $(e.subBrands).each(function(_i, _e){

            if(_e.id == id){

              e.subBrands.splice(_i,1);
              return false;

            }

        });

     }

   });

  return data;

}

console.log(removeById(data,32))
```

this function will return your whole data array without the specifiec id object

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for..of` loop to iterate each `subBrands` array, `Array.prototype.splice()` to remove object having `id` `31` from array.

```
for (let {subBrands} of data) {
  let n = 0;
  for (let {id} of subBrands) {
    if (id === 31) {
      subBrands.splice(n, 1);
      break;
    }
    ++n;
  }
}
```