# Remove an object in array from array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to delete the 1 ids of cardItems of my list with 0 ids and keep the order of the lists. what is the best way?

```
   lists: [
        {
          id: '0',
          title: 'LIST 1',
          cardItems: [
            {
              id: '0',
              text: 'Card 1',
            },
            {
              id: '1',
              text: 'Card 2',
            },
            {
              id: '2',
              text: 'Card 3',
            },
          ],
        },
    ]
```

Comment: Please provide the expected output. However, this looks like the kind of question that has been asked several times before.

Comment: Your description is not clear, please write your description clearly. Of course, I probably think your question is similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42005096/js-remove-object-from-nested-array-and-return-parent-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.find` to get the list item by id, and then remove the card item using `.filter`:

```js
const lists = [
  {
    id: '0',
    title: 'LIST 1',
    cardItems: [
      { id: '0', text: 'Card 1' },
      { id: '1', text: 'Card 2' },
      { id: '2', text: 'Card 3' },
    ],
  },
];

const removeCardItem = (list, listItemId, cardItemId) => {
  const arr = [...list];
  // get list item by id
  const item = arr.find(listItem => listItem.id === listItemId);
  // remove card item by id if found
  if(item)
    item.cardItems = item.cardItems.filter(cardItem =>
      cardItem.id !== cardItemId
    );
  return arr;
}

console.log( removeCardItem(lists, '0', '1') );
```