# Deleting object from nested JSON by name provided.It should return the rest

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, nested, logic

Hi I am new to react native,I am having a array of objects ,I want to delete the a inner object from this JSON.

```
[
  {
    Key: 1,
    exchnageArr: [
      {
        name: ”FX”
      },
      {
        name: ”MK”
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    Key: 2,
    exchnageArr: [
      {
        name: ”CK”
      },
      {
        name: ”DK”
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here I want to delete the {name:"FX"} from this JSON .If I pass "FX".How to do this,I tried but not working for me.

```
    const newDatavalues = arr.forEach((item) =>
            item.exchangeArr.forEach((subItem, index) => {
              if (subItem.name === "FX") {
               return item.exchangeArr.splice(index, 1);
           } 
       })
     );
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42005096/js-remove-object-from-nested-array-and-return-parent-array might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on each array inside one of the objects.

```js
let arr=[{Key:1,exchnageArr:[{name:"FX"},{name:"MK"}]},{Key:2,exchnageArr:[{name:"CK"},{name:"DK"}]}];
for (const o of arr)
  o.exchnageArr = o.exchnageArr.filter(x => x.name !== 'FX');
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo (`exchnageArr`, that should be `exchangeArr`) in your property names in the array (JSON).

Corrected JSON:

```js
[
  {
    Key: 1,
    exchangeArr: [
      {
        name: ”FX”
      },
      {
        name: ”MK”
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    Key: 2,
    exchangeArr: [
      {
        name: ”CK”
      },
      {
        name: ”DK”
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now your code should work fine.